# how to get return value by power shell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, return-value

In Powershell, I could this kind of command. But how can I get some return value to verify this call succeed for fail?

I would like to have some return result and check do similar task

```
$url = ("http://localhost:5000", $path -join "")
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $bearerHeader
```

Or,

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bod
```

If I could get some return, I could do something like this:-

```
if($resp -eq $false)
{
   Write-Host "Failed to upload file:" $upload.GetPath() -ForegroundColor "Red";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you define what's a successful call to your code? HTTP 200-204?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't currently return a response code like `Invoke-WebRequest` does. You could use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead, or you could use a `Try..Catch` to test for exceptions:

```
Try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bod -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to upload file:" $upload.GetPath() -ForegroundColor "Red";
}
```

From PowerShell 6 (Core) onwards you have the `-ResponseHeaderVariable` parameter for `Invoke-RestMethod` through which you can get data if the connection was successful, even if the response with empty.

For example:

```
~\Documents> Invoke-RestMethod http://xkcd.com/info.0.json -ResponseHeadersVariable Response

~\Documents> $Response

Key            Value
---            -----
Cache-Control  {max-age=300}
Connection     {keep-alive}
Date           {Fri, 12 Jan 2018 17:24:30 GMT}
Via            {1.1 varnish}
Accept-Ranges  {bytes}
Age            {115}
ETag           {"5a5846d2-1a9"}
Server         {nginx}
Vary           {Accept-Encoding}
X-Served-By    {cache-lhr6327-LHR}
X-Cache        {HIT}
X-Cache-Hits   {1}
X-Timer        {S1515777871.992127,VS0,VE3}
Content-Length {425}
Content-Type   {application/json}
Expires        {Fri, 12 Jan 2018 05:31:14 GMT}
Last-Modified  {Fri, 12 Jan 2018 05:25:38 GMT}
```